# Using colons within object destructuring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm still unfamiliar with all the magic of ES6. I saw this code in an online article and I'm not sure how `PrivateRoute` is destructuring the input props. what does `component: Component` do in this context?

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  // Code here
)
```

I understand that I can do something like this to destructure an object

```
obj = {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'};
{first, last} = obj;
```

and have `first = 'John'`, `last = 'Doe'`; however, I got confused with the introduction of a colon in the example code.

Here's a link to the full article: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/

Comment: Read the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two basic ways to use the `:` in destructuring:

1. destructuring sub objects
2. aliasing a variable

If the right hand side of the `:` is an object or array then you are destructuring a sub-object. If the right hand side is an identifier then you are aliasing the key on the left hand side of the `:`

## Destructuring Sub Objects

```
const { component: { example } } = opts

// equivalent to
const example = opts.component.example
```

## Aliasing a Variable

```
const { component: Component } = opts

// equivalent to:
const Component = opts.component
```

## Both Combined

```
const { component: { example: Component } } = opts

// equivalent to
const Component = opts.component.example
```

Comment: Please clarify why variable aliasing is needed ? Can you give some real world example ?

Comment: The most common is when you have conflicts of course such as `const { a: { value: a }, b: { value: b } } = obj`. In that example both `a` and `b` are sub objects with a same `value` field, if you destructured the value twice that would end up being an error as you're redeclaring a variable called value twice and the type is `const`. Another example is just like I have above, naming conventions where `component` is a `class` and your naming convention dictates that classes should be named with a different case such as `Component`.

Answer (score 3):

It's to use a different name for a property obtained by destructuring.

```
let obj = {
  a: 'thing A',
  b: 'thing B'
}

let { a: newVariable } = obj
console.log(newVariable) // outputs: "thing A"
```

See [MDN docs for Assigning to new variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names)

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It's a lot clearer than the others, at it doesn't have all the additional React references.

Comment: this answer is better i think.

Comment: Your answer needs correction ->  "...different name for a property.." , please change "property" to "key" as property = key + value pair in a JS object

Comment: @vikramvi what you're renaming is the key/value pair as a variable, not the key by itself

Comment: you're totally wrong here, check the accepted answer "..then you are aliasing the key on the left hand side of the..."